# Create a div similar in shape to the capital letter "I" using css/js

Tags: html, css

I am trying to achieve something similar to an `'I'` figure (in italic). I want to create a div in my HTML page with similar outline without using image.

Is there any way I can achieve the same?

I want the div to look like a bigger version of this:

> ```
>                               •
>                               _
>                              ( (
>                              )_)
> ```

Can't upload an image as SO dont permit to upload image for new members. Hope it clears my problem

Comment: What do you mean by :I want to create a div in my HTML page with similar outline without using image.?

Comment: Do you mean formatting an element as a parallelogram? With content inside? How should the content be formatted? What have you tried? Note that upright I and italic *I* are very different, and the title now refers to “I”, the text parenthetically says “in italic”.

Comment: I was able to resolve this using css
http://jsfiddle.net/aakashjain/jn5r1bja/

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS3 transformations if there's no content in the `div`. This will distort the contents in the `div`.

```
div {
    -ms-transform:skew(-30deg,0deg);
    -webkit-transform:skew(-30deg,0deg);
    transform:skew(-30deg,0deg);
}
```

Or if the content does matter you could use pseudo-elements to add two triangles to the sides of the `div`. Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/85aA4/).

```
div {
    width:120px;
    height:300px;
    background:blue;
    position:relative;
    left:120px;
}

div:before {
    content:"";
    width:0;
    height:0;
    border-top:150px solid transparent;
    border-bottom:150px solid red;
    border-right:60px solid red;
    border-left:60px solid transparent;
    position:absolute;
    left:-120px;
    top:0;
}

div:after {
    content:"";
    width:0;
    height:0;
    border-bottom:150px solid transparent;
    border-top:150px solid red;
    border-left:60px solid red;
    border-right:60px solid transparent;
    position:absolute;
    left:120px;
    top:0;
}
```

Or a similar(simpler) solution using CSS3. Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/24rLj/).

```
div {
    width:120px;
    height:300px;
    position:relative;
    left:120px;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}

div:before {
    content:"";
    width:240px;
    height:300px;
    background:blue;
    position:absolute;
    -ms-transform:skew(-21.8deg,0deg); /* arctan(300/120) */
    -webkit-transform:skew(-21.8deg,0deg);
    transform:skew(-21.8deg,0deg);
    left:-60px;
    top:0;
    z-index:-1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS3 transform rotate:

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/5G2VX/)

```
div {
  border : 0px solid black;
  border-left-width: 1px;
  transform: rotate(10deg);
  -ms-transform:rotate(10deg); 
  -webkit-transform:rotate(10deg);
  height: 12px;
  width: 1px;
}
```